# Spring JPA Transaction doesn't seems to be reused and connection pooling grows indefinetly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions

I'm using the Spring framework with Hibernate5 and dbcp2. We switch to JPA from using hibernate directly. As we did so our application stopped working.

**1) The problem**

It seems that the connection pooling is not working or not being used correctly : when we monitor the database activity we notice that the number of connections steadly grow.

In our case, a REST request is received in a controller which passes the details to the Service layer. The Service is called once per request and is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`. The service then processes the request by accessing data through DAO classes.

With this architecture only one transaction should be used for the actual business logic and one JDBC connection should be used from the pool. However the traces and the database stats shows many more connections and transactions being created.

When the request is over, many connections to the database are still alive.

Often the application get stuck on :

```
17:21:07,070 DEBUG [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager]:1020 - Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
17:21:07,070 TRACE [TransactionSynchronizationManager]:272 - Initializing transaction synchronization
```

For this particular case the extra transaction comes from a different service (to write statistics). The transaction from the service we are interested in was suspended.

Looking at the thread, it is waiting for a connection from the pool.

[Stuck getConnection() stackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78n9M.png)

We made a small test to check the transaction's propagation. The test doesn't replicate our architecture but is intended to replicate the issue.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { //
        TransactionTest.class, //
        ClientDataSourceConfig.class, //
        TransactionTest.TestFakeService.class })
@Configurable
public class TransactionTest {

    @Autowired
    DataSource primaryDataSource;
    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager primaryHibernateTransactionManager;
    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory primarySessionFactory;
    @Autowired
    TestFakeService fakeService;

    // --------------
    @Test
    public void transactionTest() {
        Tree tree = fakeService.getTree();
        fakeService.getTree2();
        assertNotNull(tree);
    }

    @Component
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public class TestFakeService {

        public Tree getTree() {
            EntityManager em = primarySessionFactory.createEntityManager();
            Tree tree = em.find(Tree.class, "ID");
            fakeService.getTree2();
            return tree;
        }

        public Tree getTree2() {
            EntityManager em = primarySessionFactory.createEntityManager();
            Tree tree = em.find(Tree.class, "ID");
            return tree;
        }
    }
}
```

Which resulted in the following trace http://pastebin.com/D7Wy65rB (without logs from initialization of the test. I used pastebin because I hit the character limit )

What we noticed from the test : 
 * We call the first method -> a transaction is created
 * The second method is called from withing the transaction -> a new transaction is created (instead of propagating the existing one)
 * The entity is fetched again (instead of using the one from Hibernate's session)

**2) The configuration**

Here is the configuration for the datasource :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:datasources.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ClientDataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**************** DATASOURCE CONFIG *****************/

    @Value("${jdbc.client.db}")
    private String dataDatabase;
    @Value("${jdbc.client.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${jdbc.client.port}")
    private String port;
    @Value("${jdbc.client.driver.class}")
    private String driverClassName; // org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    @Value("${jdbc.client.driver.name}")
    private String driverName; // mariadb
    @Value("${jdbc.client.user}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.client.pass}")
    private String password;

    /*************** HIBERNATE CONFIG ******************/

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect; // org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.current_session_context_class}")
    private String sessionContextClass; //org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext

    /*************************************/

    @Bean(name = "clientEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public EntityManagerFactory clientEntityManager(
            @Qualifier("clientDataSource") DataSource clientDataSource) {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateVendorAdapter);

        em.setDataSource(clientDataSource);
        em.setMappingResources("HibernateQueries.xml");
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { //
                "entity.package", //
        });

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", sessionContextClass);
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);
        em.afterPropertiesSet();

        return em.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "clientDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:" + driverName + "://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dataDatabase);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean(name = "clientDataSourceTx")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager clientDataSourceTx(
            @Qualifier("clientEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**3) The question**

So to summarize, we don't understand why this configuration worked flawlessly when we were using hibernate's session directly but not when using JPA's EntityManagerFactory.

Why the number of active connection to the database keep increasing without seeing any kind of logs showing connection pooling and why so many transaction are created when we designed the service / DAO layers in a way to ensure that there aren't calls to the service's methods from withing itself?